# Python: count repeated elements in a list, get key with maximal count, break ties in favor of numerically highest key

Tags: python, counter

this is my code

```
from collections import Counter
py = [1,3,2,1,3,3,3,1,2,1]
a = dict(Counter(py))
print(a)
```

the output is
`{1: 4, 3: 4, 2: 2}`
I want the max but the problem is that when the value is tie between two value then I want the value behalf on key
in this scenario How can I get the second key `3`

Comment: What do you mean, you want a tie breaker ?

Comment: What should you do when the maximum value is tied between three keys?

Comment: *"value behalf on key"* is not grammatical English, I think you mean *"key giving the maximum count, break ties by returning the (numerically) maximal key"*. Also, in your case we can assume all keys are integers.

Answer (score 0):

You can first find the maximum value among the values in the dictionary:

```
max(a.values())
```

With that, you can traverse the dictionary and filter all the keys with value not equal to the max values:

```
max_a = dict(filter(lambda elem: elem[1] == max(a.values()), a.items()))`
```

Answer (score 0):

The builtin `max` function in python takes a `key` argument, that basically tells it how to compare the values  -

In your case, you need to come up with some way to make `(3, 4)` greater than `(1, 4)` - and it turns out that is the default behavior anyway

So, simply

```
d = {1: 4, 3: 4, 2: 2}
max(d.items())
# (3, 4)
```

will give you the right result.

But, alternatively, just as an example -

```
max(d.items(), key=lambda x: int(str(x[0]) + str(x[1])))
# (3, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the `most_common` method of `collections.Counter` combined with `max` on the reversed tuple:

```
d = Counter(py)
max(d.most_common(), key=lambda e: e[::-1])
```

output: `(3, 4)`

Using the dictionary, you need to use the `items` method:

```
d = dict(Counter(py))
max(d.items(), key=lambda e: e[::-1])
```

Another approach, `zip` the values and keys to perform the max with a priority on the values, and inverse the output:

```
max(zip(d.values(),d))[::-1]
```

output: `(3, 4)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `max()` function and get the result by using the `key` argument.

```
max(c.items(), key= lambda x: (x[1],x[0]))
```

*This will first find the elements whose frequency is maximum and then within those elements find the element with the largest value.* So in this case, it will be `(3,4)`.

```
from collections import Counter
lst = [1,3,2,1,3,3,3,1,2,1]

c = Counter(lst)
print(max(c.items(), key= lambda x: (x[1],x[0])))
```

Output:

```
(3, 4)
```

Comment: print(max(a, key=lambda x:(a.get(x), x)))

Comment: this is the best result